# Regarding bitbake recipie

Tags: yocto, bitbake

What changes should make to enable dlt-system.
In build folder dlt-system application is not generating.

Manually by using command: cmake -D with dlt-system=ON it will generate but I need to generate while building please look at recipie image

[image: 1]

Comment: Did you try adding `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " dlt-daemon"` in `local.conf` file

Comment: I added image of recipe please look at it and try to solve this

Comment: Please anybody give me the propper solution. I used extra_oemake += "-D with dlt-system=ON " but it's not working

Comment: You need to provide more information, please post contents of `local.conf` file

Answer (score 0):

Your recipe supports dlt-system via `PACKAGECONFIG`.

In order to activate that flags in the compilation process, you just need to add `dlt-system` to `PACKAGECONFIG` in `.bb` or `.bbappend` file to the recipe:

```bash
PACKAGECONFIG_append = " dlt-system"
```

If you want to add it from `local.conf`:

```bash
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-name_append = " dlt-system"
```

Just change `name` with your recipe name.

This will add `-DWITH_DLT_SYSTEM=ON` to `EXTRA_OECMAKE` which is used in `do_configure` of the `cmake` class.